# I want to update an image in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to update an image in Laravel but it throws the error

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string

It seems that `$this->storeImage($ad, 'photo1')` in the `update()` function does not work. I tried first just with one image but I can't figure it out how to make it work. I tried doing the same thing in the `update()` method as in the `store()` method but it doesn't work.

AdController.php

```
public function store()
{
    $ad = new Ad();

    request()->validate([
    'title' => ['required', 'min:10'],
    'description' => 'required',
    'guarantee'=>'required',
    'city' => 'required',
    'address' => 'required',
    'rent' => 'required',
    'type' => 'required',
    'partitioning' => 'required',
    'number_of_rooms' => 'required',
    'culinary' => 'required',
    'phone' => 'required',
    'date_available' => 'required',
    // 'min_age' => ['min:1', 'max:99'],
    // 'max_age' => ['min:1', 'max:99'],
    'photo1' => 'required'
    ]);

    $ad -> title = request('title');
    $ad -> description = request('description');
    $ad -> city = request('city');
    $ad -> address = request('address');
    $ad -> rent = request('rent');
    $ad -> type = request('type');
    $ad -> partitioning = request('partitioning');
    $ad -> number_of_rooms = request('number_of_rooms');
    $ad -> utilities_price = request('utilities_price');
    $ad -> RadioFurniture = request('RadioFurniture');
    $ad -> air_conditioning = request('air_conditioning');
    $ad -> parking = request('parking');
    $ad -> terace = request('terace');
    $ad -> garden = request('garden');
    $ad -> elevator = request('elevator');
    $ad -> dishes_machine = request('dishes_machine');
    $ad -> clothes_machine = request('clothes_machine');
    $ad -> cable_internet = request('cable_internet');
    $ad -> wifi_internet = request('wifi_internet');
    $ad -> TV = request('TV');
    $ad -> microwaves = request('microwaves');
    $ad -> fridge = request('fridge');
    $ad -> own_heat = request('own_heat');
    $ad -> about_me = request('about_me');
    $ad -> my_age = request('my_age');
    $ad -> number_of_residents = request('number_of_residents');
    $ad -> my_sex = request('my_sex');
    $ad -> cleaning = request('cleaning');
    $ad -> guests = request('guests');
    $ad -> parties = request('parties');
    $ad -> wake_up = request('wake_up');
    $ad -> sleep_hour = request('sleep_hour');
    $ad -> culinary = request('culinary');
    $ad -> smoke = request('smoke');
    $ad -> work_hours = request('work_hours');
    $ad -> min_age = request('min_age');
    $ad -> max_age = request('max_age');
    $ad -> smoker_buddy = request('smoker_buddy');
    $ad -> RadioStudents = request('RadioStudents');
    $ad -> RadioPets = request('RadioPets');
    $ad -> AcceptsPets = request('AcceptsPets');
    $ad -> phone = request('phone');
    $ad -> facebook = request('facebook');
    $ad -> photo1 = request('photo1');
    $ad -> photo2 = request('photo2');
    $ad -> photo3 = request('photo3');
    $ad -> photo4 = request('photo4');
    $ad -> photo5 = request('photo5');
    $ad -> photo6 = request('photo6');
    $ad -> photo7 = request('photo7');
    $ad -> photo8 = request('photo8');
    $ad -> guarantee = request('guarantee');
    $ad -> owner_id = auth()->id();
    $ad -> date_available = request('date_available');

    $this->storeImage($ad,'photo1');
    $this->storeImage($ad,'photo2');
    $this->storeImage($ad,'photo3');
    $this->storeImage($ad,'photo4');
    $this->storeImage($ad,'photo5');
    $this->storeImage($ad,'photo6');
    $this->storeImage($ad,'photo7');
    $this->storeImage($ad,'photo8');


    if($ad->max_age<$ad->min_age){
        return redirect('/adauga')->withErrors('Intervalul de varsta trebuie sa fie unul valid(Ex:19-22)')->withInput();
    }

    $ad->save();


    return redirect('/home');
}

// Here is the update function using the $id
public function update($id){
    $ad = Ad::findOrFail($id);

    $ad -> title = request('title');
    $ad -> description = request('description');
    $ad -> city = request('city');
    $ad -> address = request('address');
    $ad -> rent = request('rent');
    $ad -> type = request('type');
    $ad -> partitioning = request('partitioning');
    $ad -> number_of_rooms = request('number_of_rooms');
    $ad -> utilities_price = request('utilities_price');
    $ad -> RadioFurniture = request('RadioFurniture');
    $ad -> air_conditioning = request('air_conditioning');
    $ad -> parking = request('parking');
    $ad -> terace = request('terace');
    $ad -> garden = request('garden');
    $ad -> elevator = request('elevator');
    $ad -> dishes_machine = request('dishes_machine');
    $ad -> clothes_machine = request('clothes_machine');
    $ad -> cable_internet = request('cable_internet');
    $ad -> wifi_internet = request('wifi_internet');
    $ad -> TV = request('TV');
    $ad -> microwaves = request('microwaves');
    $ad -> fridge = request('fridge');
    $ad -> own_heat = request('own_heat');
    $ad -> about_me = request('about_me');
    $ad -> my_age = request('my_age');
    $ad -> number_of_residents = request('number_of_residents');
    $ad -> my_sex = request('my_sex');
    $ad -> cleaning = request('cleaning');
    $ad -> guests = request('guests');
    $ad -> parties = request('parties');
    $ad -> wake_up = request('wake_up');
    $ad -> sleep_hour = request('sleep_hour');
    $ad -> culinary = request('culinary');
    $ad -> smoke = request('smoke');
    $ad -> work_hours = request('work_hours');
    $ad -> min_age = request('min_age');
    $ad -> max_age = request('max_age');
    $ad -> smoker_buddy = request('smoker_buddy');
    $ad -> RadioStudents = request('RadioStudents');
    $ad -> RadioPets = request('RadioPets');
    $ad -> AcceptsPets = request('AcceptsPets');
    $ad -> phone = request('phone');
    $ad -> facebook = request('facebook');
    $ad -> instagram = request('instagram');
    $ad -> guarantee = request('guarantee');
    $ad-> date_available = request('date_available');
    $ad-> photo1 = request('photo1');

    $this->storeImage($ad, 'photo1');

    $ad -> owner_id = auth()->id();

    $ad -> save();

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Here is the `storeImage()` function:

```
private function storeImage($ad, $photo){
    if(request()->has($photo)) {
        $ad->$photo = $ad->title.$ad->date_available.$photo.'.'.request()->$photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $imageExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'bmp', 'svg', 'svgz', 'cgm', 'djv', 'djvu', 'ico', 'ief','jpe', 'pbm', 'pgm', 'pnm', 'ppm', 'ras', 'rgb', 'tif', 'tiff', 'wbmp', 'xbm', 'xpm', 'xwd'];

        $foo = \File::extension($ad->$photo);
        if(in_array($foo, $imageExtensions))
        {
            $width = Image::make(request()->$photo)->width();
            $height = Image::make(request()->$photo)->height();

            $img = Image::make(request()->$photo->getRealPath())
                ->resize($width/3,$height/3)
                ->orientate()
                ->save('images/'.$ad->$photo,40);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like the `$this->storeImage($ad, 'photo1');` does not work in the `update()` method. Any ideas in how I can replace it? What do I have to change? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

first of all, instead of all the `$ad->param = request('param')`you can do:

```
 $input = $request->all();
 $ad->update($input);
```

This will update all the fields in $ad with given input.

or you can even do:

```
$input = $request->all()
$ad = \App\Models\Ad::updateOrCreate($id, $input);
$add->save();
```

This will clean your code some bit.

And for the saving of images you best can read the documentation of laravel:
[File upload in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#file-uploads)